# Play Sound File with C++ and Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, audio

How can I play a sound file using Qt 5 and C++? I have tried `QSound` but I am told it does not workin Ubuntu (my current Operating System) and I have heard of `Phonon` but the library does not seem to be available in my Qt Package.

Comment: What makes you think QSound doesn't work on Ubuntu?

Comment: When I tried it, it did not work and after viewing some information about one it it's functions to know if it works with my system or not, I got a false response.

Comment: You'll either need to get Qt's multimedia APIs working, in which case you can use QSound or QAudioOutput or similar, or find some non-Qt-based API to use for playing sounds.  If you program is a Qt-based app, then the former approach would be preferable.

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296326/how-to-play-sound-in-qt5-qt4-migration ?

Comment: I did not come across this but I don't seem to have the 'Qt Multimedia' library and I cannot find it in the repos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Qt5**

```
QFile inputFile;
QAudioOutput* audio;
inputFile.setFileName("/tmp/test.raw");
inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QAudioFormat format;
// Set up the format, eg.
format.setFrequency(7600);
format.setChannels(1);
format.setSampleSize(6);
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
    qWarning()<<"raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.";
    return;
}

audio = new QAudioOutput(format, this);

connect(audio,SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)),SLOT(finishedPlaying(QAudio::State)));
 audio->start(&inputFile);
```

**C++**

Use `BOOL PlaySound(LPCTSTR pszSound, HMODULE hmod, DWORD fdwSound);`

```
#pragma comment (lib, "winmm.lib")
...
PlaySound(TEXT("recycle.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
```

Set `SND_` option as`SND_ASYNC`.

[`PlaySound` reference : MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680.aspx)

Anyway you can listen the audio.

Comment: Isn't `PlaySound` a Windows function? I thought OP is using Ubuntu. Not to mention, the Qt code looks like it was completely copied from [Bart's answer to 14296326](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14296398/14227825); under CC BY-SA 3.0 you should at least attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Install the package `sox` that contains the utility `play`. Or you can use `mplayer` or any console media player. Then use `QProcess` to start playing sound file.

```
#include <QProcess>

.......

QProcess qprocess;
qprocess.startDetached("play",QStringList()<<"wav/alarm-clock-01.wav");

.......
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for me but it does I am getting an error when using the audio files from my 'qrc' resources file. any ideas?

Comment: @OmariCelestine As far as I know, an external program (one launched with QProcess) does not have access to the resources in the application. In any case, I would not consider this option as the best option since it does not allow for interaction with the player, such as pausing, playing etc. Rather consider the answer of Bryant if you need access to resources or if you want to interact with the player.